# Mysql complicated query help needed

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume, we have 2 related tables

```
Table1:
id item_id(References to Table2:id) rating

Table2:
id title day position
```

I need to bult a query:
For all Table2 items check Table1:rating and put its position(ASC) to Table1:position but only for specific day. Every day - new rating. 1,2 ... 1000

```
Exmpl:
Table1:
id item_id rating
1  1       2
2  2       1555
3  3       280
```

We need to get:

```
Table2:
 id title day position
 1  test1 1   1
 2  test2 1   3
 3  test3 1   2
 N  ....  2   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table2 a
        INNER JOIN table1 b
            ON a.id = b.item_id
WHERE   day BETWEEN day_1 AND day_2
ORDER   BY a.position ASC
```

give this a try,

```
UPDATE  table2 e
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  c.*, 
                    @rank:=@rank+1 row_rank
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  a.*, b.*
                        FROM    table2 a
                                INNER JOIN table1 b
                                    ON a.id = b.item_id
                        WHERE   day BETWEEN day_1 AND day_2
                    ) c, (SELECT @rank:=0) d
            ORDER   BY c.rating ASC
        ) f ON e.ID = f.ID
SET     e.position = f.row_rank
```

Comment: I need to update Table2:position by Table1:rating

Comment: `UPDATE`? where is the value coming from? you haven't said *update* in your question.

Comment: i need some clarification, if you have rating like this `100,67,2`, what will you store on the position? `100,67,2` or `3,2,1` based on rank?

Comment: From Table1.rating. Exmpl: we have 2, 1555, 280 values; And we need to set Table2 related item position by order: 2 - lowest so table1.position = 1, 1555 - position 3 and 280 position is 2.

Comment: You are right. May be it can be called rank )